# Searching in large memory mapped files

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, optimization, io

I have a large data structure stored in memory mapped file. Data structure is very simple:

```
struct Header {
    ...some metadata...
    uint32_t index_size;
    uint64_t index[]
};
```

This header is placed in the beginning of the file, it uses a structure hack - variable sized structure, size of the last element is not set in stone and can be changed.

```
char* mmaped_region = ...;  // This memory comes from memory mapped file!
Header* pheader = reinterpret_cast<Header*>(mmaped_region);
```

Memory mapped region starts with `Header` and Header::index_size contains correct length of the Header::index array. This array contains offsets of the data elements, we can do this:

```
uint64_t offset = pheader->index[x];
DataItem* item = reinterpret_cast<DataItem*>(mmaped_region + offset);
// At this point, variable item contains pointer to data element
// if variable x contains correct index value (less than pheader->index_size)
```

All the data elements is sorted (less than relation defined for data elements). Their are stored in the same memory mapped region as Header but starting from the end to the beginning. Data elements can't be moved, because their are of variable size, instead of that - indexes in header are moved during sort procedure. This is very much like B-tree page in modern databases, index array is usually called an indirection vector.

**Searches**

This data-structure is searched with interpolation search algorithm (with limited amount of steps) and than with binary search. First, I have a whole `index` array to search, I'm trying to calculate - where searched element can be stored if distribution is uniform. I get some calculated index - look at element at this index and it usually doesn't match. Than I narrow the search range and repeat. Number of interpolation search steps is limited by some small number. After that data-structure is searched with binary search. This works very good with small data-sets, because distribution is usually uniform. Few iterations of the interpolation search and we're done.

**Problem definition.**
Memory mapped region can be very large in reality. For testing I use 32Gb file backed storage and search for some random keys. This is very slow because this pattern cause lot of random disk reads (all data can't be cached in memory).

What can be done here? I think that setting MADV_RANDOM with `madvise` syscall can help, but probably not very much. I want to get on par with B-tree search speed. Maybe it is possible to use `mincore` syscall to check what data-elements can be painlessly checked during interpolation search? Maybe I can use prefetching of some sort?

Comment: I can certainly believe this feels slow. I've had to fix a similar problem, but that was glacially slow because it used a database on CD. Harddisk seeks are ~10ms, CD seeks are ~150 ms. With just 20 seeks (1 million items) that already took 3 seconds per query. An index containing actual keys took just 6 MB (It compresses quite well), and a CD drive can read that in about 1 second.

Comment: `MADV_RANDOM` will **not** help. All it does is completely disable readahead, which means no more and no less than in addition to getting hard page faults on random locations, you _also_ get them on hits within the first few hundred kilobytes. The only two things that do help are (a) having more physical RAM than the file's size and (b) improving locality of reference.

Comment: @Damon: Technically it's sufficient to have just the keys in memory, the single file access to retrieve the right record isn't going to kill you.

Comment: @MSalters: True, though even a few single seeks are still painful (they do add up). Unluckily, I don't really have a good solution at hand (obviously). If the dataset doesn't fit into RAM, and if you can't rearrange data so you can page in whole big chunks, and if you can't predict what you'll need at least 50-100ms ahead of time, it's pretty much a problem with no real solution :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interpolation search appears to be a good idea here. It usually has a small benefit, but in this case even a small number of iterations saved helps a lot since they're s slow (disk I/O).

However, real databases duplicate the actual key values in their indices. The space overhead for that is fully justified in the performance improvement. Btrees are a further improvement because they pack multiple related nodes in a single contiguous block of memory, further reducing disk seeks.

This is probably the correct solution for you as well. You should duplicate the keys to avoid disk I/O. You can probably get away by duplicating the keys in a separate structure and keeping that that fully in memory, if you can't alter the existing header.

A compromise is possible, where you just cache the top (2^N)-1 keys for the first N levels of binary search. That means you have to give up your interpolation for that part of the search, but as noted before interpolation is not a huge win anyway. The disk seeks saved will easily pay off. Even caching just the median key (N=1) will already save you one disk seek per lookup. And you can still use interpolation once you've run out of the cache.

In comparison, any attempt to fiddle with memory mapping parameters will give you a few percent speed improvement at best. "On par with B-trees" is **not** going to happen. If your algorithm needs those physical seeks, you lose. No magical pixie dust will fix a bad algorithm or a bad datastructure.

Comment: +1 for "No magical pixie dust will fix a bad algorithm or a bad data structure."

Comment: I need really fast append operation so I use this data-structure. It's very much like the write-ahead log in databases. With b-tree we need to copy things, split nodes and so on. With this data-structure I can write millions of entries per second. Your remark about magical pixie dust is absolutely correct but searching in b-tree requires log_m(N) disk seeks and interpolation search requires log(log(N)) and depending on the m - interpolation can be even faster. In reality I expect that interpolation + binary search will be much slower anyway, but I know what I'm doing :)

Comment: "On par with b-tree" can be 10x slower, this is OK. 100x or more is not OK, I believe this is achievable with this algorithms.

Comment: @Lazin: If you have 32 GB of objects, you may have a billion or more objects, but probably at least a million. So you'd be looking at 20 or 30 seeks whereas the cached index with values would allow you to find the right value directly (in case of a million objects, all keys in memory) or almost directly (in case of a billion objects, 16 million keys cached, interpolation over remaining 128 objects so ~4 seeks)

Comment: @Lazin: If you need that fast an append, store the tree plus a "Recent update cache" of <=128 objects. Search both in parallel. When the "recent update cache" overflows, you update the Btree in a single operation. This means you need to rebalance the tree once for every 128 inserts.

Comment: @MSalters b-tree is hard to implement. Moreover it's hard to do many other things - recovery, backups etc. This is my hobby project, that's why I'm trying to avoid complexity. There is plenty of reasons not to use b-trees.

Comment: I think about indexing, caching keys (or part of the keys) in inderection vector is not feasable because of large overhead, inderection vector is 4Gb for 32Gb storage, it will become 8Gb if I decide to cache keys in inderection vector. I'm thinking about constructing a histogram sketch (approximation) in constant amount of space. This can speedup interpolation search and guide it directly to a single page with data.

Comment: @Lazin: consider aligning the objects at 8 or 16 byte boundaries; that means you can store the offsets in 32 bits (since the lowest 3 or 4 bits would be zero, you don't store them). An efficient interpolation data structure is equivalent to the restricted key cache I suggested, so that indeed should help.